# shell script ffmpeg stops after 2 jobs

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, shell-script

I have a pretty simple shell script and after doing the first two jobs, it just stops and sits there, doesnt do anything, it doesnt seem to matter what the third job is, if I switch the order etc, it will not finish it.

Any ideas would be great...

Here is my shell script

```
for f in "$@"
do
name=$(basename "$f")
dir=$(dirname "$f")
/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -y -b 250k -deinterlace -vcodec vp8 -acodec libvorbis -nostdin "$dir/webm/${name%.*}.webm"
/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -y -b 250k -strict experimental -deinterlace -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -nostdin "$dir/mp4/${name%.*}.mp4"
/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -y -ss 00:00:15.000 -deinterlace -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 720x480 "$dir/img/${name%.*}.jpg"
done
```

This may help, as I am running this script within Automator, which may be part of the issue...it seems like it is timing out and then just sits there...

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of the backticks?

Comment: Saw it in another script, thought it may help...but other than that, there is non...they are actually removed now

Comment: Where exactly does it stop? Does it actually call `ffmpeg`? Does it work if you use something other than `ffmpeg`? (Note that the order of your FFmpeg options is a little off in your case. It *probably* doesn't matter, but global options like `-y`, `-nostdin` should always come first.) What happens when you put all the commands in a subshell (i.e. in parentheses `(ffmpeg -i … )`)?

Comment: I moved -y and -nostdin to the beginning, but putting each subshell in parentheses throws an error, `syntax error near unexpected token ')'`

Comment: Please update your post with the syntax you were using for subshells. What about other commands than FFmpeg?

Comment: My knowledge of shell scripts are super limited, so when you tell me to put parentheses around it, I literally put parentheses around each line of code...like this `(/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -y -b 250k -deinterlace -vcodec vp8 -acodec libvorbis -nostdin "$dir/webm/${name%.*}.webm")` also if I put an echo commaned before it works, but If I put an echo command after the ffmpeg it does not work, as it never gets to that command

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882759/shell-script-ffmpeg-stops-after-2-jobs – do not cross post, please. Also, if your issue was the nostdin option missing from one command, then saying that the order of the commands didn't have an effect doesn't really make sense.